# What is the scope of JS variables in anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does this code returns $products empty? If I test for $products inside the function it does show data... but once it finishes I can't seem to get the data.

```
var $products = new Array();
connection.query($sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for(i=0; i< rows.length; i++)
    {
        $products[rows[i].source_identifier] = "xyz";
    }

});
connection.end();

console.log($products); // Shows empty.
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't *return* it empty; there's no `return` statement.  The issue is that the operation is **asynchronous**. When your `console.log()` call runs, the query has not yet completed.

Move your `console.log()` call to *inside* that callback function, after the `for` loop. (Also declare "i" with `var` !!!)

The whole point of using APIs that involve callbacks like that is to cope with the fact that the operations are asynchronous. If they were synchronous, it'd be weird to design such an interface.

Comment: My first instinct was that this was an asynch issue....  I tried putting a return to the call back but I get weird data..  can you show a quick example? Thank you.

Comment: @smorhaim Adding a `return` does nothing because it's just returning it to whatever called your callback within the async context established in your call to `connection.query`.  In short, you can't access the populated `$products` outside of the callback.

Comment: @smorhaim, the call to `connection.query` returns (almost) immediately. You just left a callback function to be run when the results arrive.